# Axios GET request sends empty req.body to server

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request in my React app but Axios seems to send an empty request body for some reason. I know there's (most likely) nothing wrong in the backend as I'm able to make the requests perfectly fine with Insomnia. I've tried the following till now and none of the seem to work:

```
const response = await axios.get(URL, { email })

const response = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: URL,
    data: { email }
})
```

I'm using the express.json() middleware in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1)

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

So do not rely on body data for GET request and use appropriate HTTP method like POST, PUT etc.

Moreover, if you want to send Query params with your GET request, both code snippets you shared above will not work. Instead do it like below.

```
// using get method
const response = await axios.get(URL, {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  });


// using Axios API
const response = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: URL,
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! The res.body part was a typo I made while writing the question have updated it now.